How can I compute the gradient of a row-vector valued function?
In excercise 2.1 c) i) here: https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/1-eY0fGfnIWOEfZaBLYLejEGgNRW4tPOu?usp=sharing one of the tasks is to compute the gradient $\frac{\partial y}{\partial A}$ for $y=AX \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 3}$ with $A\in \mathbb{R}^{1\times 2}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 3}$.
The answer is: $\frac{\partial y}{\partial A} = X^T$. But why? In the excercise they use the result to show that the gradient of a scalar-valued function $\mathscr{L}$ can be computed with the chain rule. And yes - it's true, I need the transposition, otherwise I don't get the right result. But what is the formal reason for the transposition? It seems to have something to do with $y$'s property of being a row vector. What is the rule or theorem that shows what the shape of the gradient must be in this case?

Let's calculate the derivative from the definition in multivariable calculus:
$$D_Ay =  \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_1} & \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial A_2} \\
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_1} & \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial A_2} \\
\frac{\partial y_3}{\partial A_1} & \frac{\partial y_3}{\partial A_2} 
\end{bmatrix}=X^T.$$
It falls out of the definition there isn't any deeper reason.

Which definition do you refer to? The definition of the Jacobian here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient?

I still don't get it. I should be able to use the derivative to approximate $y(A)$ like this: $y(A)=y(0) + D_A y \cdot (A - 0)= X^T A$, right? But that doesn't fit, I cannot compute $X^TA$!

Given a differentiable map $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, the total derivative at $x$ $D_xf$ is computed as the matrix of partials derivatives in the usual way.  Your statement is true by Taylor's theorem for multivariable functions, but that's not how you find what the total derivative is. For that you calculate via the formula like I have done.

The gradient is the derivative of a real valued smooth function between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$. It's a special case of the total derivative of a map between $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$.
